# How to make form below the carousal with media queries while resizing the viewport

Tags: css, media-queries, responsiveness

> There is a bootstrap carousal(full-width) on my page and the carousal have registration form an i want to bring the form below the carousel on resizing the screen,I am using media queries but my form is coming above the text of my page below is my screenshot and code can anyone help to sort the problem

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/corousal1.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3><strong>Healing People,</strong>Changing lives<br/>
                    Personalized Treatments that are safe,
                    Sure and Scientific
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
           <div class="multi-form">
              <form id="msform">
       <fieldset>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-btn-primary" value="Book An Appointment">
                <button type="button" class="next action-button btn-btn-primary" style="background-color:#3B5998 !important;"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Connect With Facebook</button>
            </fieldset>
       </form>
        </div>
```

> **media queries**

```
@media (max-width:786px) {
   .multi-form {
    margin-top: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
}
}
```

> full page screenshot
>   [image]
>   Responsive page screenshot
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `absolute` position ? you can design the div with absolute position and values in `%`.

For Example :

```
 .multi-form {
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;  
    right:0%;
    left:0%;
    bottom:0%;
  }
```

This will work for all resolution.

**EDIT :**

*Absolute positioning means that the element is taken completely out of the normal flow of the page layout. As far as the rest of the elements on the page are concerned, the absolutely positioned element simply doesn't exist. The element itself is then drawn separately, sort of "on top" of everything else, at the position you specify using the left, right, top and bottom attributes.*

You'll definitely want to check out this [positioning article](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101)   from A List Apart.

And finally please try to make `my corousel` is **absolute** positioned and `my form` is **relative** positioned. So that your component will work in all resolution as your expectations.

Comment: my corousel is relative positioned  and my form is absolute positioned

Comment: The `absolute` positioned elements always placed in fixed position based on your properties. Whereas `relative` positioned elements are relative to their ancestor elements. So _your form element is place above text_